# Many calls to the same number with .call files

Tags: node.js, asterisk

I need help, I have created a Nodejs application to make automatic calls every 15 seconds from the web with Asterisk, however, when I create the .call files and move them to the folder /outoging, some numbers are called several times although I have the MaxRetries: 1 option

```
const interval = setInterval(function () {

  Registers.findOneAndUpdate({state: "READY"}, {state: "SEND"}, (err, registerDB) => {

            if (err) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    ok: false,
                    err
                });
            }

            if (registerDB) {
                if (typeCampaign === "audio") {
                    console.log("Audio Campaign selected");
                    fileContent = `Channel: SIP/outgoing/${registerDB.number} \nMaxRetries: 1 \nRetryTime: 60 \nWaitTime: 30 \nContext: automatic-calls \nExtension: ${extAudio} \nSetvar: NUMBER=${registerDB.number} \nSetvar: CAMPAIGN=${registerDB.campaign}`;
                } else if (typeCampaign === "dynamic") {
                    console.log("Dynamic Campaign selected");
                    fileContent = `Channel: SIP/outgoing/${registerDB.number} \nMaxRetries: 1 \nRetryTime: 60 \nWaitTime: 30 \nContext: automatic-calls \nExtension: ${extDynamic} \nSetvar: NAME=${registerDB.name} \nSetvar: NUMBER=${registerDB.number} \nSetvar: CAMPAIGN=${registerDB.campaign}`;
                }

                let oldPath = __dirname + sourcePath + registerDB.number + ".call";

                console.log(oldPath);
                let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + sourcePath + registerDB.number + ".call");
                writeStream.write(fileContent);

                fs.rename(oldPath, dstPath + registerDB.number + ".call", function (err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                        return res.status(500).json({
                            ok: false,
                            message: "No se pudo generar la llaamda"
                        });
                    }
                });

                writeStream.on('finish', () => {
                    console.log("Archivo Creado");
                });
            } else {
                return res.status(200).json({
                    ok: true,
                    message: "Tarea Finalizada"
                });
            }
        });

        counter++;

        if (counter === parseInt(req.body.number)) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }

    }, 15000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First I have say you that write your own dialer core is bad idea even for expert. It require special experience with dialing cores, a lot of issues WILL arise.
Recommended method is use some other core like vicidial.

One call is

```
MaxRetries: 0
```

If you use

```
MaxRetries: 1
```

That mean **TWO** calls with standard retry time.

Comment: Yes I understand but it make many retries when it get congestion, if Asterisk receive congestion it continue retries calls.

asterisk congestion (circuits busy) try dial many times

Is there any solution for not retry although it has congestion?